# Join table performance

Tags: mysql, performance

This question is more about performance.

Assume that there are two tables one with millions of records and one with some thousands of records in a DB like MySQL. By this example, I am trying to show a very unbalanced situation. So the question is, how expensive would be the (inner) join operation? (join on for example user_goup from the 1st table and the id from the second). do you think that this architecture can be scaled to more records in tables?

Comment: We really need to see the query.  Is it `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`?  Are there sufficient indexes to let the Optimizer start with either table?  Is there a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Please show relevant query, tables and indexes, and the query plan

Comment: See the quesiton please

Answer (score 1):

It would depend more on the distribution of data in both tables. The total number of records in each table is much less of a factor here. If `Table1`, which has millions of rows, only had 1 row that matched on the `JOIN` conditions to `Table2` (the table with thousands of rows) and an `INNER JOIN` was used then only 1 row would be returned in the result set. (This is known as the cardinality - the number of rows that match your predicates.) With proper indexing this should be achievable in milliseconds. This is true for almost any number of total rows in both tables (e.g. even if the table had billions of rows).

But there are a lot of factors that influence the outcome above which your question leaves out, so that's just one example. If the above tables weren't properly indexed (e.g. on `user_goup` and on `id` for each table respectively) then you'd possibly run into a full table scan, which would be a lot slower on the table with millions of records. The type of `JOIN` being done would also result in a different outcome which could exhibit different performance from my above example, and again depending on how the data is distributed and how much data is actually being returned, would also impact the total runtime.

Comment: Great explanation thanks. this could answer my question but I wait for other opinions as well. thanks very much again.

Answer (score 1):

> ... one with millions of records and one with some thousands of records ... a very unbalanced situation ... how expensive would be the join operation?

It depends entirely on the Query, how "good" the Indexes are on the fields that you're joining on and *what else* is going on in the database at the same time.

Say you have a banking application.
You can join from the "Accounts" table (with thousands of rows) to the "Transactions" table (millions of rows) using the Account Number field.  As long as that's indexed on both tables (PK in Account, FK in Transactions) then the query will run [very] well.  Databases all over the world run like this every day.

The trouble comes when you try to join on fields that *aren't* indexed or that aren't good choices for indexes (say an "Account Active" flag that only has two values - it's essential, yes, but on it's own, it's a very *poor* discriminator to choose between records).
The trouble can also come from a [poorly-written] query, where something about it "tricks" the database into doing things the "wrong" way around - putting some value in the Transactions table through a *function* might force the database to Table Scan that first, before joining to the other.

The only real way to find out how things are going to work is to **Test** them.
Run you queries against a representative database, preferably under a representative workload.